# HTTP Form Post to external website from Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, locker-service, security-review

I am working with a client to develop a managed package. Here is the requirement in brief:

1. User clicks a button in a lightning component which is added to Contact detail page.
2. The button click handler, in turn, redirects the user to an external HTTP (unsecured) website (not a REST API endpoint) which accepts form data. Form data is going to be basic contact details like First Name, Last Name, Email.
3. The HTTP website internally reads the form data, encodes it and sends it as URL parameter to another HTTPS website.
4. We are able to achieve this by creating a form on the fly (using document.createElement) on the button click using vanilla javascript and submit that form along with the necessary data.

Even though this seems to work fine, I am not confident if this approach will pass the Salesforce security review. It would be of great help if someone can confirm my doubt and provide the right advice if this approach is not correct.

Thank you!

Comment: Why can you not directly send the data to the https website, skipping the step 2? Is there any reason?, interested to know that.

Comment: When we redirect to HTTP endpoint, which is an aspx page, in Step 2, some logic executes to create a record in the database in the client's app. Unfortunately, we don't have an option to skip Step 2 at this point in time.

Comment: Can you not use Lightning Container to excess external websites?